# How do I combine the first element of 2 array together into a string array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
    String quantityArray[] = GetStringArray(quantity);
    String foodItemArray[] = GetStringArray(fooditems);
```

this is to change from ArrayList to a String Array

```
    int n1 = fooditems.size();
    int n2 = quantity.size();

    for(int s = 0; s<n1;s++){

        totalFood[s] = quantityArray[s] + foodItemArray[s];
    }
```

I cannot make this totalFood[] function to work as it just keeps crashing my app

```
public static String[] GetStringArray(ArrayList<String> arr) {
    // declaration and initialise String Array
    String str[] = new String[arr.size()];
    // ArrayList to Array Conversion
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
        // Assign each value to String array
        str[j] = arr.get(j);
    }
    return str;
}
```

The error that pops up is (Attempt to write to null array)

Comment: Where are you allocating the `totalFood` array?

Comment: How did you initialize your totalFoods array? I can't see that in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `totalFood` array is allocated.

Arrays are themselves `Object`s in Java.

For example:

```
totalFood = new String[n1];
```

This is because `totalFood` seems to be `null` according to the error you are seeing. You need to allocate some space (`n1` references to be precise for the above example) for the `String`s resulting from the concatenation to be stored at. You can take a look at the corresponding Java tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Also make sure `n1` is equal to `n2` which should be equal also to the size of the `totalFood` array in order to not overrun any of them in your loop.

Finally, there are 2 handy [`Collection#toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-) methods which will do what you are doing in your `GetStringArray` method. You can use it for example like so:

```
String quantityArray[] = quantity.toArray(new String[quantity.size()]);
```

Using the `toArray` method seems not to be related to the problem, but I just mention it for completeness.

Comment: Yeap for the totalFood was the issue so after i initialized i got it working thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] GetStringArray(ArrayList<String> arr) {
        String str[] = new String[arr.size()];
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
            str[j] = arr.get(j);
        }
        return Arrays.stream(str).filter(s -> s!=null).toArray(String[]::new);
    }
```